# Azure Monitor resource changes

Tags: azure, monitor, changelog

I'm trying to see the change history of a resource in Azure Activity Logs but it only shows an action "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/write" and username as an information which is valuable to me.

Is it possible to see details of any change for example size or disk changes, added removed resources and previous and new values?

Answer (score 0):

You definitely cannot see previous values. As for the other part of the question.

You can look up correlationID in the Azure Monitor and use `Get-AzureRmLog -CorrelationID xxx -DetailedOutput` and work your way from there, but I'm not sure how much reasonable information can you get from that.